# CSS: chaining effects from one element to another

Tags: jquery, css

I have image A and image B. They are located in the different places on the page. When hovering over image A there is a css animation attached. I'd like to attach and trigger same animation for the image B, when hovering over image A. Is it possible with CSS? Should I better use jQuery? And if jQuery then how to trigger a css animation on the element?

Comment: Sounds like it can be done with CSS, but can you post some markup so we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: You can do this if element B is nested inside element A, but I don't think you can if they're completely disjoint elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>**This cannot be done with just CSS.**</s> *There are [some ways of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9978916/370103), but not certain on the cross-browser support available.*

If you wish for animation to occur on ImageB while hovering ImageA, you will require jQuery.

You mention CSS animation on hover. Therefore I assume you mean different styles for the psuedo state?:

```
.imageA:hover
{
   //styles
}
```

This could be changed to:

```
.imageA:hover, .hoverAnimation
{
   //styles
}
```

Now you can apply the `hoverAnimation` class to ImageB while hovering over ImageA using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("img.imageA").hover(function(){
     $("img.ImageB").addClass("hoverAnimation");
  }
  ,function(){
     $("img.ImageB").removeClass("hoverAnimation");
  });
});
```

[**-- DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/3errQ/)

Comment: Lies! It can absolutely be done in CSS so long as A and B are, at least, siblings (or be is contained in a sibling of A). See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely possible in CSS, **as long as B can be targeted below A (if A and B are siblings, or B is in a container that is a sibling of A)**. In other words, `img.A` needs to be in the CSS Selector for `img.B`.

Something like:

```
/* if A is immediately preceded by B */
img.A:hover {...}
img.A:hover + img.B {...}

/* if A is later preceded by B (same parent element) */
img.A:hover {...}
img.A:hover ~ img.B {...}

/* if B is in a container that is a sibling of A */
img.A:hover {...}
img.A:hover ~ div.container img.B {...}
```

**Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/GE7UP/**

These selectors won't work in IE6, but since you're using CSS animations, I doubt you care :) Now, if `img.B` cannot be targeted below `img.A` then you would need to use Javascript to manipulate classnames.

Comment: @Curt Cool, thanks. These selectors work in everything above IE6 (since the OP is using CSS animations, he should be good to go care-free).

Answer (score 0):

Edited to address requested problem (with thanks to Curt):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function mouseoverHandler(e){
        $(image B).addClass('animate-result-class');
        $(image A).one('mouseout', mouseoutHandler);
    }

    function mouseoutHandler(e){
        $(image B).addClass('animate-result-class');
        $(image A).one('mouseover', mouseoverHandler);
    }
    $(image A).one('mouseover', mouseoverHandler);
});
```

Comment: OP has asked for animation on B, when hovering A

Answer (score 0):

create class for both of A and B then apply this class on hovering using jQuery [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) option